# how to validate email id is already register or not

Tags: users

```
 function lawyer_register_form_submit($form,&$form_state) 
{
$mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];
$new_password = user_password();
$edit = array(
  'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
  'pass' => $new_password,
  'mail' => $mail,
  'init' => $mail,
  'status' => 1,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  );
  if(!db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE mail = :mail;", array(':mail' =>  $mail))->fetchField())
  {
  $to = $form_state['values']['mail'];
  $subject = 'Lawandmoney New account created';
  $headers = "From: admin@lawandmoney.info\nContent-type: text/html";
  $body = 'A new user account has been created for you at <a  href="http://us.lawandmoney.info">us.lawandmoney.info</a>.<br /> Your login details are as  follows:<br />Username: <b>'.$form_state['values']['name'].'</b><br /> Password:  <b>'.$new_password.'</b> <br /><br /> Please login to <a  href="http://us.lawandmoney.info">us.lawandmoney.org</a> and change your password.<br />';
     user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
     if($form_state['values']['send_message'] == 1)
     {
     mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
     drupal_set_message("Sussessful register.Please check your Email for login   deatils."); 
     }
     else 
     {  
     drupal_set_message("mail not send.");
     }
     }
     else 
     {
     drupal_set_message("You are already register.");
     }
```

we created a custom user registration form.now we have to checked if user is already register then its give error like You are already register, data will not inserted into database and mail not send to user.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You stated a fact... please ask a question. Is your code wrong? What do you see? What do you want us to tell you about your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  function module_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $new_password=user_password();
  $edit = array(
  'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
  'pass' => $new_password,
  'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
  'init' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
  'status' => 1,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  );
  $mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];
  if(!db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE mail = :mail;", array(':mail' =>  $mail))->fetchField())
  {
  $to = $form_state['values']['mail'];
  $subject = 'test';
  $headers = "From: test@test.info\nContent-type: text/html";
  $body = 'test';
  user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
  drupal_set_message("Sussessful register"); 
  }
 else
 {
 drupal_set_message("Please check your Email for login deatils."); 
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `hook_form_alter`:

```
function module_(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $user_login_forms = array('user_login', 'user_login_block');
  if (in_array($form_id, $user_login_forms)) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'my_validate_function';
  }
}

function my_validate_function(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
  // Drupal 6:
  if (!db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE name = '%s';", $name))) {
    // User doesn't exist
  }
  // Drupal 7:
  if (!db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE name = :name;", array(':name' => $name))->fetchField()) {
    // User doesn't exist
   }
}
```

It's better to query the DB directly in this case than than using user_load as it hooks into other modules as well.

Comment: Interesting theory - why would you recommend not using the API for this exactly? Simply for speed?

Comment: Yes! Simply for speed..

Comment: Well ok then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7
to check if a user already exists, if so display a message with

```
drupal_set_message
```

Otherwise, register the user

Comment: i already write a drupal_set_message() to alert. when i write this code page goes blank

Comment: In the beginning of you code, just use:
 `$mail = $form_state['values']['mail'];
if(!$mail){add new user}`

Comment: If you are getting a white screen there will be errors in your error logs. If you add any errors to your original post it will help resolve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting the blank page(or error) it's probably because of this - `$mail = $form_state['values']['mail']` line. You're passing `$form_submit` to the `lawyer_register_form_submit`, but getting the mail from `$form_state` which is giving `undefined variable` error, after that you're passing undefined `$mail` to the `db_query`...

EDIT:

ok, here is the solution:
(this goes to `_validate($form, &$form_state)` function):

```
$exist = db_select('users', 'us')
        ->fields('us')
        ->condition('mail', $mail, '=')
        ->execute()
        ->rowCount();

if ($exist) {
  form_set_error(null, 'You are already register');
}
```

submit callback, just create a user, send a mail:

```
...
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
...
```

Comment: I made the changes but not working. please let me know we can write a code in this way is correct or wrong

Comment: @RahulVarma read your own code carefully. you left `$form_submit['values']['send_message'] == 1`..

Comment: @RahulVarma you should read the logs..

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know why you have developed a new user registration form, as you can customize the one Drupal has, by going to:

> Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings

Moreover, the code you have written is likely doing the thing you want! But by the Drupal practices, you're not following the recommended way.The following line is checking the repetition of **user email**:

```
if(!db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {users} WHERE mail = :mail;", array(':mail' =>  $mail))->fetchField())
```

Try to check the values in the hook_form_validate and set the error by [form_set_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) function.

Comment: in my website there is two registration are required. one for normal user and second one for doctor. so i create a custom registration form for only user. so after login user can see doctors details.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you are looking for doing?

Comment: If it's only about giving notification to user to enter another username, you should use the same conditional code line for username inside form validate.

Comment: actually i create a custom user registration form.now i have to check if user is already register then gives error 'you are already register', data not inserted to database and mail not send to user.